# Java object instantiation - where

Tags: java, object

I am fairly new to Java, this particular question has arisen because I am trying to do some Swing programming for the first time but it is a general Java question.

I have a class with some instance variables, I need to create one (and only one) object to hold the variables and methods.  Is there a best/approved place to create the object, should it be declared and instantiated in the class' attribute definition :

```
public class TestClass {
    static TestClass tC = new TestClass();
    ...
```

or declared in the class' attributes definition and instantiated by a static method (e.g. `main` later on) :

```
public class TestClass {
    static TestClass tC;
    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tc = new TestClass();
    }
```

Or somewhere else, does it matter?

Comment: Maybe take a look at http://wikijava.org/wiki/Singleton_Factory_patterns_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or somewhere else, does it matter?

It certainly does matter, if you see it generally enough.

Placing the initialization inside the `main` method will be relevant only to those uses of your class where this particular `main` method is executed. If your class has any scope of usage larger than a single program, that particular avenue of initialization will be as good as non-existent.

Placing the initialization inline with declaration ensures that the field is initialized for *all* users of the class, independent of the code path taken to access it.

Additionally note that in real-world programs, hardcoding singleton initialization like that very often interferes with the full extent of intended usage. The singleton often depends on some kind of initialization data, and that data may not be available at class initialization time. There may be several independent "zones" in a larger program, each needing a differently initialized singleton. Testing concerns usually imply substituting a mock implementation instead of your class, and so on.

So, either of your approaches may work for you currently, but also *neither* of them may be enough in a more complex scenario.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that.  Neither matters for this tiny programme but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate the variable where you declare it as a field, it will be created as the class is first initialised (that is, when it's first "touched".) If you initialise it in the main method, then it will be initialised, well, whenever that particular line in that method is executed.

If it doesn't make a difference functionally, then one could argue that the inline declaration ensures that it's never null when a method comes to deference it (this could be further strengthened by making the field `final` if you can.) In the grand scheme of things though, it probably doesn't matter too much.